# equivalent of python boto for google storage

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, boto

I am looking for the easiest way to upload or download a file to/from a google storage bucket using a python script (.py).

For Amazon S3, there is the excellent package boto, is there something similar for Google storage?

Note that I tried the following code:

```
from boto import connect_gs      

gs_conn = connect_gs(gs_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     gs_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
bucket = gs_conn.get_bucket('gs://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
keys = bucket.get_all_keys()
for key in keys:
    print(key)
```

And the process get stucked without an error but without listing nothing.

Comment: I believe boto works with Google Cloud Storage, too.  Or maybe they have changed the API since it was first introduced?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: *"Note that this file is a priori not a json or xml so I can't use these APIs"*  Um.  The language of the API has nothing at all to do with the payload of the files you want to store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google wrote a plugin for boto which works with Google Cloud Storage: [gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin).

And Google wrote a [page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary?hl=en) on how to use that plugin.